# Как правильно связать объекты Entity в Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть таблица lu (универсальный справочник, который хранит много разных данных, которые используются во многих таблицах), с полями id, tag, code
Есть таблица agr с полями id, text, range_id, finance

Таблица с agr связана с lu следующим образом:

1. Поле range_id содержит значение поля lu.id, где lu.tag = 7
2. Поле finance содержит значение поля lu.code, где lu.tag = 5

Как правильно реализовать связь этих Entity, для правильного добавления записи в таблицу agr

Классы, которые описывают данные таблицы привел ниже

Класс Agr

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "agr")
public class Agr {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "createdate")
    private Date createdate;

    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "info")
    private String info;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private int status;

    @Column(name = "typ")
    private String typ;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private int code;

    @Column(name = "bgndate")
    private Date bgndate;

    @Column(name = "enddate")
    private Date enddate;

    @Column(name = "finance")
    private int finance;

    @Column(name = "range_type_id")
    private int range_type_id;

    @Column(name = "num")
    private int num;

    public Agr() {
    }

    public Agr(Date createdate, String text, String info, int status, String typ, int code,
               Date bgndate, Date enddate, int finance, int range_type_id, int num) {
        this.createdate = createdate;
        this.text = text;
        this.info = info;
        this.status = status;
        this.typ = typ;
        this.code = code;
        this.bgndate = bgndate;
        this.enddate = enddate;
        this.finance = finance;
        this.range_type_id = range_type_id;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getCreatedate() {
        return createdate;
    }

    public void setCreatedate(Date createdate) {
        this.createdate = createdate;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getTyp() {
        return typ;
    }

    public void setTyp(String typ) {
        this.typ = typ;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Date getBgndate() {
        return bgndate;
    }

    public void setBgndate(Date bgndate) {
        this.bgndate = bgndate;
    }

    public Date getEnddate() {
        return enddate;
    }

    public void setEnddate(Date enddate) {
        this.enddate = enddate;
    }

    public int getFinance() {
        return finance;
    }

    public void setFinance(int finance) {
        this.finance = finance;
    }

    public int getRange_type_id() {
        return range_type_id;
    }

    public void setRange_type_id(int range_type_id) {
        this.range_type_id = range_type_id;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }
}
```

Класс Lu

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lu")
public class Lu implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "tag")
    private int tag;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private int status;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private int code;

    public Lu() {
    }

    public Lu (String text, int tag, int status, int code) {
        this.text = text;
        this.tag = tag;
        this.status = status;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(int tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Изучите такие аннотации как, именно с помощью них, описывается связь полей в разных таблицах.

```
@ManyToOne
@OneToMany
@ManyToMany
@JoinColumn
```

Пример, Component хранит ссылку на автора и на задание следующим образом:

```
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "component")
public class Component {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn
    private User author;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn
    private Task task;
    private Lang lang;
    private String name;
    private String path;
    private String compilationError;
    private String runtimeError;
    private Boolean crash;
    @Enumerated
    private ComponentStatus status;
    private Integer testPassed;
    private Integer testCount;
    private Long runtimeDuration;
    private Long memoryUsed;
    private Long bootTimestamp;
}
```

При этом, задание и автор ничего не знают о Component.